# template specialization for static data member

Tags: c++, templates

Following code can be compiled with MSVC 14.1 but not with Clang 5.0.1.

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    static int a[];
};
int C<int>::a[1] = { 1 };
```

Clang's error message is:

> error: template specialization requires 'template<>'

Is this code compliant with C++ standard?
I found related passage in [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) as follows.

> When defining a member of an explicitly specialized class template
>   outside the body of the class,  the syntax template <> is not used

Comment: I'm more concerned about `static int a[];`.

Comment: Can you describe your concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an `explicitly specialized class template` (that would be if you had for example a fully-specialized `C<Foo>`) so that passage doesn't apply to your code here. You do in fact need `template<>` for this.